# index out of range in when we using multi-dimentional array

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var sections = ["A","B","C","D"]

    var items = [["General","Privacy",""],["icloud","Maps","News"],["safari","Photos and Camera","Game Center"],["Twitter","Facebook","Flicker"]]
    var secItems = ["iclouds","Maps","Safari"]
    var thirItems = ["Twitter","General","Privacy","icloud"]
    var imgItems = ["settings_ios7_ios_7.png","privacy.jpeg","icloud.png","Google-Maps-4.0-for-iOS-app-icon-small.png","news.jpeg","safari_ios7_ios_7 (1).png","photos.jpeg","game_center_ios7_ios_7.png","twitter.jpeg","facebook.jpeg","flicker.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Settings"


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "ABC"
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.imgName.image = UIImage(named: imgItems[indexPath.row])
        cell.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowIcon.png")

        return cell
    }
}
```

Getting error `index out of range` in here: 
`cell.lblName.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` 
(when we take 4 by 4 multi-dimensional array it works fine, but we take different array it's getting `index out of range`.

Comment: Check where indexpath section and row are being set. If it's in a loop, check the increments.

Answer (score 1):

In numberOfRowsInSection you are returning `items.count`    which will be count of total array in your Item  array... which is actually number of sections.count which is wrong. It should be  `items[section].count`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}
```